# Mesh does not move along with bones in pose mode (uses rigify armature) Ver 2.75

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigify

As the title says, my mesh does not deform along with the rigify bones in pose mode, even though the bones are in pose, and not rest position. I have already adjusted the weighting, and I know that in the past, it's worked completely fine. I have no idea as to what caused it, though I believe it has something to do with changing the weights on some of my objects.

In the past versions of Blender, selecting multiple vertices in edit mode during this stage would have crashed the program, though that seems to be fixed in the latest version, giving me some hope that this is a mistake on my part, or a fixable bug.

Below is a screenshot of what the problem is like. I've also attached the .blend file in the link for anyone willing to lend a hand.
[image: whatthefuckseriously]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/hnb7p4zo83a9evw/Natlie_rig.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played around with your .blend a little (good you uploaded it...). I realized that the Armature modifire got removed. I dont know how this happend.

[image: this i how the modifire should be set up for your model]

Just add the modifire again and you will be fine.
In the picture you can see the needed settings.

I also realized that your armature is scaled extremely big. preess <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> to reset the scale if this size wasn't intended.

By the way you can delete all the annoying meshes in the last layer. they arn't needed anymore.

Comment: I didn't realize there was anything on the last layer until you mentioned it. Thanks for your answer man, really helped. :D

Comment: Where do you check this setting in Blender 2.8?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your rig can be saved. In the outliner select the objects within the red box one after another and (re)add an armature modifier to each as shown below.

[image]

In case you aren't awere of make sure that that you configure IK or FK correctly here is an example for FK.

[image]

Comment: Where do you re-add the armature modifier in Blender 2.8?